# Can PHP & MySQL serve a dynamic ogg file

Tags: php, mysql, ogg

**Foreword**

I have been reading the ogg documents, particularly the [framing](http://www.xiph.org/ogg/doc/framing.html) part.

Of course I didn't understand much. But from what I did understand, an ogg file is made of a sequence of ogg page (*64kB max*). The "absolute granule position" determines the frame number of an ogg video in each page header.

**Actual question**

Suppose I have some large video files, e.g. security footages stored locally. Splitting the video files into ogg pages and store them in a web server's MySQL table with each page's corresponding timestamps. (Max Blob size of 64kB)

When requested to view the video from time *A* to time *B*, a php script would query the table and get the ogg pages in between that time span. And would increment the frame number from 0 to *x* and echo it out with proper mime type.

Is this plausible?

Comment: Do NOT store large video files in a database. It's not designed for it and it simply won't work. Store the video data in the file system as a conventional file and serve it from there. Keep your metadata in the database and use that to find the video files.

Comment: We had no problem storing large datasets in the database. your solution sounds logical, there could also be some header at the beginning of the file which you may need to construct dynamically.

Comment: Keep in mind memory and execution time restrictions of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm absolutely not an expert about *ogg* files, but according to what you said, the video stream is in fact a sequence of *ogg pages*.

It seems rather interesting to store each page as a blob in your database, and *dynamically* reassemble those pages on request. As *DevZerO* suggested in a comment, you probably will have to reconstruct file header on request too.

From the client point of view, all will be like downloading a file (I don't think PHP is suitable for *streaming*?).

In fact *I think* this is a great idea, and if you achieve some preliminary steps on that way, I would be glad to have some feed-backs about it ;)